# Braces on both side of the cases

Tags: formatting

how can i achieve that braces are on both sides, so in the beginning and the end of each cases environment? I Think this looks better than now.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

% This first part of the file is called the PREAMBLE. It includes
% customizations and command definitions. The preamble is everything
% between \documentclass and \begin{document}.

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}  % set the margins to 1in on all sides
\usepackage{graphicx}              % to include figures
\usepackage{amsmath}               % great math stuff
\usepackage{amsfonts}              % for blackboard bold, etc
\usepackage{amsthm}                % better theorem environments

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}

\begin{thm}

There is \begin{cases} test1 \\ 
test2 \end{cases} if \begin{cases} condo \\ 
condo \end{cases} to do.

\end{thm}

\end{document}
```